# Assigning PHP object when object key unknown but sub key known in the object

Tags: php, object

Below lists the output of a mySQL query in PHP PDO. The object contains multiple columns from two tables that are then to be combined into a single object.

Some rows in the same table are children of others as identified by the column `parent_ID`. These children then need to be added to the object of the parent as do their children and so on and so on.

As much as I can achieve this simply for the first two levels of children I cannot see a way without performing another foreach to achieve this beyond the first to layers of the object.

This example should add clarity to the above:

```
foreach($components as $component){
    if($component->parent_ID < 0){
      $output->{$component->ID} = $component;
    }
    else if($output->{$content->parent_ID}){
      $output->{$content->parent_ID}->child->{$component->ID} = $component;
    }
    else if($output->?->child->{$conent->parent_ID}){
      $output->?->child->{$content->parent_ID}->child->{$component->ID} = $component;
    }
  }
```

Not on the third line there is an ? where there would normally be an ID. This is because we now do not know what that ID is going to be. In the first layer we did because it would be the parent_ID but this line is dealing with the children of children of a parent.

Comment: Did I get you right that you have a tree?

Comment: @Rulisp Is that the technical term?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)

Comment: That would seem to be correct then.

Comment: ok. And how many records do you have?

Comment: The average example would include around 15.

Answer (score 1):

So, as I far I understood from comments and assuming that you don't have a lot of records in DB, it's seems to me the best way is to preload all rows from DB and then build a tree using this function

```
public function buildTree(array &$objects) {
        /** thanks to tz-lom */
        $index = array();
        $relations = array();

        foreach($objects as $key => $object) {
            $index[$object->getId()] = $object->setChildren(array());


            $relations[$object->getParentId()][] = $object;


            if ($object->getParentId()) {
                unset($objects[$key]);
            }
        }

        foreach ($relations as $parent => $children) {
            foreach ($children as $_children) {
                if ($parent && isset($index[$parent])) {
                    $index[$parent]->addChildren($_children->setParent($index[$parent]));

                }
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

P.S. Really, I don't see other way without `foreach` in `foreach`. At least, it's not recursive

Comment: I shall give it a try. Thanks

Comment: also recursive functions are great for tree like structures

Comment: @Kazz thanks for your comment. In first function there is a comment which I deleted with working code(accidentally). Code fixed